# Sorting dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift-playground

I want to know why there is difference in the output?

```
let cities = ["Shanghai": 450_00_000, "Seoul": 90_00_000]

let new = cities.mapValues { "\($0 / 10_00_000) million people" }
print(new)
// ["Shanghai": "45 million people", "Seoul": "9 million people"]



let cities = ["Shanghai": 45000000, "Seoul": 9000000]

let new = cities.mapValues { "\($0 / 10_00_000) million people" }
print(new)
// ["Seoul": "9 million people", "Shanghai": "45 million people"]
```

Answer (score -1):

A dictionary is by definition not sorted. There is no guaranteed sorting order. Actually, in recent versions of Swift sorting order is *intentionally* randomised.

BTW. You really really need to learn how to write a million. One million = 1000000 = 1_000_000. Not 1_00_000. That's one hundred thousand.

Comment: Thanks for correcting million but I am still not clear about the randomisation.